# Implement a Custom Exception that Fails a Unit Test as Inconclusive

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

Using the test tools built into Visual Studio (in my case VS 2013, though I believe this extends to other versions as well), a 'TestMethod' (any method marked with a `[TestMethod]` attribute) can result in 1 of 3 statuses after being run:

- Passed
- Skipped/Inconclusive
- Failed

A test is passed if it runs to completion with no uncaught exceptions. A test fails it throws an uncaught exception. A test is inconclusive if it throws a special type of uncaught exception: `AssertInconclusiveException`.

My question is, is it possible (in, say, a `[TestCleanup]` method) to treat an custom uncaught exception similarly to the `AssertInconclusiveException` and set the test status to 'Inconclusive' instead of 'Failed'? Or is the recognition of `AssertInconclusiveException` as a special exception built into Visual Studio itself? What I'm looking for, in rough pseudocode form, is roughly:

```
[TestCleanup]
public void TestCleanup()
{
    if(this.TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome == UnitTestOutcome.Failed 
        && this.TestContext.UncaughtException.GetType() == typeof(MyCustomException))
    {
        this.TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome = UnitTestOutcome.Inconclusive;
    }
}
```

This would be used as part of an integration test suite to mark a test as inconclusive whenever the setup method for the test throws a special `SetupFailureException` (usually indicative of broken downstream system that is not the one under test).

I've been able to produce the desired behavior in the interim by defining:

```
public class SetupFailedException : AssertInconclusiveException
{
}

// example test that demonstrates desired behavior
[TestMethod]
public void TestThatFailsAsInconclusiveByThrowingUncaughtSpecialException()
{
    throw new SetupFailedException();
}
```

But this seems messy since the thrown exception has nothing to do with an assertion and prevents custom exceptions which should fail tests as inconclusive from inheriting from any other abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

The Inconclusive recognition is built into the test framework, by the time you get to cleanup, it's too late to change a fail into an inconclusive.

It feels like you should really be catching the exceptions from within your integration tests anyway, since this shows that you're recognising the method your testing can throw a certain type of exception and that the right thing to do is to ignore the result in that situation.

If you need to have multiple exceptions that can be detected like this, I'd be tempted to have them implement an interface, so that the catch block can just check if any exceptions caught implement that interface.

If you wanted to minimize the impact/visibility on the rest of your test code then you could wrap the call that could fail in an action, in which case your code might look something like this:

The interface:

```
public interface ISomeNonCriticalException {
}
```

The Caller code:

```
public void CallPossiblyInconclusiveMethod(Action something) {
    try {
        something();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        if (ex is ISomeNonCriticalException) Assert.Inconclusive();
        else throw;
    }
}
```

And in your test:

```
CallPossiblyInconclusiveMethod(()=>SomeMethodThatMightFail());
```